# How best to show four previews in a card?

Tags: comparison, preview, card-views

I have a problem, I need to show the following information in the card for comparing 3D models: a preview of the original model and a preview of its details, a preview of a similar model, and a preview of its details and information on a similar model (name, application number, degree of similarity, buttons "Add to report", "View model").
The previews must be on the same level for comparison. I am attaching a link to Figma.
[image]
https://www.figma.com/file/VmZMp0L2rLcPoJqxyUTfJQ/Untitled?node-id=0%3A24

Comment: There's no 'best' way because your particular use case may be the only one out there. So, what are the use cases for this particular page/component? Who would use it and why?

Comment: @Nathan I see. This component will be on the comparison results page. There can be ten or more such cards.  The user (the expert who evaluates the models) should immediately understand what coincided (model / another model, part of model / another model) and also see information (name, number, etc.) of a similar model in the card.

Comment: What's the difference between a preview of the model and a preview of its details? In your figma mockup the two blue and two grey images look very similar.